# zoom_start in folium is not working when I excute it

Tags: python, folium

I'm trying to generate a map with `zoom_start=6`.
When I execute it doesn't apply the zoom start

```py
map = folium.Map(lacation=[38.58, -99.09], zoom_start=6, tiles="Stamen Terrain")
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: If I execute your code it works for me. Watch out, you have a typo there, it's `location` not `lacation`